# MongoDB Entity is not saving even after Success

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, typescript, mongoose

This is the Model

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var PostSchema = new Schema({
        post_author: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
        post_text: String,
        total_comments: { type: Number, 'default': 0 },
        total_likes: { type: Number, 'default': 0 },
        likes_users: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
        comments: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Comment" }],
        attachments: {
            images: [], videos: []
        },
        loc :  { type: {type:String}, coordinates: [Number]},
        isActive: { type: Boolean, 'default': true },
        createdAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now }
    });
    // PostSchema.index({loc: '2dsphere'});
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    comment_user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    comment_text: String,
    isActive: { type: Boolean, 'default': true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

This is Controller

```
 Post = require('./post.model');
var postMapper = require('./post.mapper');
var pm = new postMapper.PostMapper();

exports.create = function (req: Request, res: Response) {
    var user = req.user;
    var postModel = pm.toSchema(req.body,user);
    postModel.save((err, post) => {
        if (err) { return res.send(err); }
        res.status(201).json({ error: false, post: post });
    });
};
```

and here is the Mapper

```
var Post = require('./post.model');
export class PostMapper {
    //new post creation
    toSchema(data, user) {
        var attachments = data.attachments ? { images: data.attachments.images, videos: data.attachments.videos } : {}
        return new Post({
            post_text: data.post_text,
            // loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [data.longitude, data.latitude] },
            attachments: attachments,
            post_author: user._id
        })
    }
}
```

I am getting no error But still there is no document in posts table.
I checked that proper values are there in data which I am passing in  toSchema method of Mapper in Above code.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Found answer by myself

Issue was there because I was using two Exports in same file.

I just separated that and its working fine.